# What is the name of AB×B×A=BBB puzzles?

Tags: mathematics, letters, puzzle-identification, number-property

Some puzzles goes as follows: Solve **AB×B×A=BBB**, where different letters denote different numbers and A and B are not zero.

What is the name for these types of puzzles?

Edit. I fixed my mistake in the puzzle,
now it has solution.

Comment: Incidentally, that particular puzzle has no solution.

Comment: @dan04, thank you for comment, i have fixed the puzzle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a type of puzzle called a "cryptarithm" or an "alphametic". We have many examples of this type of puzzle under the [alphametic](/questions/tagged/alphametic) tag.

Answer (score 4):

(And for completeness, the answer)

> A=3, B=7. This is because BBB is divisible by 111, so we must have either 37 or 74 in any factorisation of BBB (37 is prime) into 1 or 2 digit numbers. Trying both, only AB=37 works.

Comment: The solution can be even simpler - first divide by B (since it's nonzero) to get AB*A=111, and the only factorisation of 111 is 37*3.